# Animate opacity and position

Tags: javascript, css

I came across [this pen at CodePen](http://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/NxaQmo), and I have a couple of problem's with it. First let's explain what the code does:

In the `input` event, there's a `forEach` loop that iterates through all the `lis` and checks for a matching regex, then hides (or more accurately, animates the `opacity` to 0) the `li` accordingly. It then has a `while` loop (in the `forEach` loop) that iterates **again** through all the `lis` and applies the appropriate `translateY` to the `lis` (because setting `opacity` to 0 doesn't remove the element).

**Problems**

**1 -** So it comes out, if you have 200 `lis`, it will iterate (200 * 200 =) 40,000 times! I don't think that's very efficient.

**2 -** Another problem is, if a certain amount of `lis` get filtered out the scroll bar still allows you to scroll down past what's there, so your scrolling down only to see nothing. Check this problem out in the example below.

The obvious solution to the first two problems would be to set `display: none` instead of setting `opacity: 0`. This way you don't have to reiterate through all `lis` 200 times because `display: none` automatically removes the 'empty' space... which as you guessed also solves the second problem.

The problem with that solution is `display: none` doesn't animate.

How can I achieve the same animation without hitting the above problems?

#### CodePen

(Couldn't insert a code snippet due to the character limit. Here's the relevant JavaScript code:)

```
searchElem.addEventListener("input", function() {
    var rgx = new RegExp(this.value.replace(/([.^$|*+?()\[\]{}\\-])/g, "\\$1"), 'i');
    searchArray.forEach(function(el, idx) {
        if (transitionEnd) {
            if (rgx.test(el)) cells[idx].removeAttribute('class');
            else cells[idx].className = 'hidden';

            var i = -1,
                cellPosition = 0;
            while (++i < cellLength) {
                if (cells[i].className != "hidden") 
                    cells[i].style.transform = "translateY(" + (cellPosition++ * cellHeight) + "px)";
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Please no jQuery answers.**

Comment: Instead of using a `transition`, did you consider using a keyframe animation? `display: block` or `inline` for 0-99% and `display: none` at 100%?

Comment: With **CSS3** javascript is not needed, see: https://jsfiddle.net/arifbdev/vaLatLvx/#&togetherjs=a7jl5x2axg

Comment: @DarkFalcon Do you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/18cdgjt9/ It doesn't animate at all

Comment: @ArifBurhan Can you show how that fixes the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid both the scrollbar issue and the repeat loops by avoiding absolute positioning of `li` elements and transitioning the `height` of the `li` along with its `opacity`.

The following is what I had done:

- Removed the `position: absolute` from the `li` because absolute positioning means all the `li` are placed at the same point and thus need to be translated (`translateY`) in order for them to be displayed one below the other.
- Added a fixed height (`height: 20px`) to the `li`. CSS transitions cannot transition values to/from auto and so we need to give a fixed height for the `li`. I think setting a fixed height should be fine for your case because all of them look like search results which will not wrap to multiple lines.
- Changed the `transition` setting to transition all properties (or you can specifically transition the height and opacity alone also) instead of just opacity and transform.
- Modified the `hidden` class' CSS to include `height: 0px` and `overflow: hidden`. This meas the element gets no height when it is getting hidden (the overflow is also hidden) and so the need for the `translateY` (which is what the second loop does) and problem with scroll bars are avoided.
- No JS changes other than removal of the extra `while` loop is required. This is because addition of the `hidden` class automatically produces both the fade and the move up effects.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 20px; /* fixed height, set whatever is fit for your case */
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0; /* produces the fade effect */
  height: 0px; /* transition height to 0px to produce move up effect */
  overflow: hidden; /* avoids the text from showing through when height is 0 */
}
```

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/PNoeNj) (not added a snippet again due to character limit restriction)

---

In the above code (and demo), the `opacity` and `height` are transitioned at the same time with same duration and so the `opacity` transition does not have much visual effect. If the `opacity` change has to be visible before the `height` transition kicks in, then add a delay to the `height` transition like in the below code:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 20px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out, height .5s ease-in-out .1s;
}
```

---

In your original snippet, the `li` items slide into their place on load and if you need the same effect, it can be produced by setting `class='hidden'` to all `li` at the start and then remove the class with JS.

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/MyWGbZ)

Comment: Why the complex regular expression when the entire input is regular words , with no uppercase ?

Comment: @ArifBurhan: That's not for me to change. It wasn't related to the question and so I left it as-is.

Comment: @Harry In my project, the way the `li` is accessed in the css is like this: `#searchesOverallWrapper li`. When I do that, the height doesn't change. But when it's just `li`, the height does change. Why does that happen, and How can I make the height change also when it's `#searchesOverallWrapper li`?

Comment: @Jessica #searchesOverallWrapper li has a higher specificity (101) than .hidden (whose specificity is 010). Try changing the CSS selector .hidden to #searchesOverallWrapper li.hidden and it should work. If it still doesn't please give me a Fiddle and I will look into it in the morning. It's midnight here :)

Comment: @Harry That fixed it! Thanks! Wow! You work at late hours!

Answer (score 0):

@DarkFalcon you need Browser specific Animation properties, like:

```
     -webkit-animation: KEYFRAME-NAME 3s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes KEYFRAME-NAME {
0%   { opacity: 0; }
50%  {opacity:.3;}
100% { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: Did you see my comment above?

Comment: Also, this should be a comment, **not** an answer!